# Погибший не пострадал?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Слушаю новости, рассказывают  об очередном происшествии: двое погибших, семеро  пострадавших. Вспомнилось,  как раньше, когда только начали в новостях передавать информацию о пострадавших, такое разделение значения: не выжил - погибший, выжил  - пострадавший - очень резало слух. Словно бы погибший не пострадал. За много лет прислушалась, недоумевать перестала. Приняла как своеобразную терминологию журналистов. Но все-таки насколько верно, с вашей точки зрения, такое разделение значений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос "верно - неверно" тут не стоит. Если терминология сложилась, то с ней приходится считаться. Даже логичность терминологии - предмет весьма тонкий. Так что можно говорить только по поводу. 
Терминология это не журналистская, а МЧСовская и отчасти - милицейская. Она "на гражданке" заменила военную, "убитых столько-то, раненых - столько-то". Против этой военной никто, вроде, не возражает. Хотя вопрос может быть точно такой же. Убитый ведь тоже раненый. Строго говоря, умирают от ранений несовместимых с жизнью (это тоже, кстати, термин "из протокола"). И большой разницы, произошло это сразу после ранения или через какое-то время, нет.
Короче, причин для возмущения терминологией я не вижу никаких.

Answer (score 0):

для behemothus
Отменный совет!!!